# UICollectionView Growing/Shrinking Cells on Scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make each cell grow/shrink if it becomes active/inactive in a horizontal collection view as the user scrolls it. I tried a few methods such as a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass with an overridden prepareLayout() but I'm having trouble getting the cell to grow with a nice animation.

Does anyone have sample code to make cells grow while scrolling a collection? Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use a carousel instead.

Comment: Here's an example using a custom layout: https://www.raywenderlich.com/99087/swift-expanding-cells-ios-collection-views